# Python: Syntax error IF Else statement

Tags: python-3.x

basically down the bottom of my code im using

```
if size == 1:
while L == y:
    name = input('apllicant: ')
    numeral = int(input('dollars: '))
    location = input('North or South location: ')
    if location == 'North' or 'South':
        print('Thank You!\n')
        calculate()
        L = input('Do you want to log another (y/n)? '
    else:
        location = input('North or South : ')
else:
     L = input('Do you want to log another (y/n)? ')
```

I get a syntax error on line 10 with the else statement, I have no idea why it keeps happening.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add tab after the if clause.The syntax of the if...else statement is: 

   `if expression:
       statement(s)
   ....
   else:
       statement(s)`

Answer (score 0):

I corrected some ident errors and a parenthesis at line 9

```
if size == 1:
    while L == y:
        name = input('apllicant: ')
        numeral = int(input('dollars: '))
        location = input('North or South location: ')
        if location == 'North' or 'South':
            print('Thank You!\n')
            calculate()
            loan = input('Do you want to log another (y/n)? ')
        else:
            location = input('North or South : ')
else:
    loan = input('Do you want to log another (y/n)? ')
```